# Unhandled error in Google Drive SDK, Python client library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

We copy and create clone Google Docs available in our system. In general it is working fine, but in some unknown scenarios, we face this kind of trackback.

Using:
Python
Appengine
Service Accounts
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/

Here is the trace:

```
   doc = apiclient.copyFile("originalDocId",mimeType, description="Doc Template",defaultPermissions={ 'value': None , 'type': "anyone",  'role': "writer" })
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/googleAPIClientV3/locusClient.py", line 142, in copyFile
    body=body).execute()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/apiclient/http.py", line 676, in execute
    headers=self.headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/oauth2client/client.py", line 420, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1436, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1188, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~unkonown-app/ver-no-26-4/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1171, in _conn_request
    content = response.read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

We need to debug and know why this happens, but it might take time. So ppl if any one faced same problem and found a work around.

Thanks in advance...

Adding another message from error stack

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 503 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<dodc ID>/copy?pinned=true&alt=json returned "Backend Error">
```

Comment: `An error occurred: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/<doc id>/copy?pinned=true&alt=json returned "Forbidden">` another kind.

Comment: there is similar kind of error today too>500 Internal Server Error
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
} Happening for last 8hrs